# Is there a standard Font Dialog for winrt?

Tags: c++-winrt

Want to display a Font Choice dialog appropriate for UWP app. Is there such a class in winrt? Or do we need to roll our own?

Answer (score 0):

I should have searched for Font Picker. Found a discussion in another forum that seems to have an answer: No. There is no standard font picker for winrt. Seems like something that would be a useful addition!